# Python: Sorting the contents of a .txt file in numerical order that contains symbols

Tags: python, sorting, csv, numerical

I have a text file that contains one integer per line, along with random characters such as \|: . I would like to sort them numerically.

I currently know how to do it with only integers in the file.

```
import csv
import operator

sample = open('sampledata.txt')

csv1 = csv.reader(sample)

sort = sorted(csv1, key=lambda x : int(x[0]))
for eachline in sort:
    print eachline
```

Example of text file:

```
:279::
     ::123::/\  \
      ::562::___
  ::482::  |:|  |
::183::
 ::528::     ___
```

What code do I need in order for these characters to be ignored.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `int(x[0])`, which just parses the first character, get all characters that are digits and then combine them, with `int(''.join(c for c in x if c.isdigit()))`.